# Url-router API design question

Tags: c#, url-routing, web-frameworks, api-design

I'm creating a Url router for a web framework. Trying to make as friendly to use as possible. The API looks something like:

```
Route[] Routes = {
    new Route(@"/user:(?<id>\d+)", "UserController.View")
};
```

Where it would route any Url that matches that regex to that method, which might look something like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public void View(int id)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

It handles the type-casting automatically.

There is a correlation between `(?<id>...)` and the arguments that the method takes. The `View()` function **must** accept all the arguments provided by the name captures.  However, it can accept *more* arguments as long as they're optional. For example, that regex would also match the function `View(int id, int extraArg=2)`, since we don't really need the `extraArg` to call the function.

The question is, should that route also match the function `View()` -- with no arguments? The `id` capture can easily be discarded and we can still call the function just fine. Or should it throw an exception (as it does presently)?

Answer (score 1):

Take the best programming approach: you don't want the user to encounter any errors.
Seeing that the user could accidentally/deliberately put extra parameters in at any stage, I'd just take the necessary ones, and ignore the rest.

Comment: Are we sure we don't want the user to see any errors? Isn't it an error to add more args in the pattern than are actually accepted? Yes, errors are nasty, but it could also save him future headache trying to hunt down... well, actually, it'd be pretty easy to see which variables are missing, but it does open up one more problem. If we allow loose matching like this, it would match *both* `View()` and `View(int id)` which is a valid overload. Which should it choose then?

Comment: Interesting problem, but I was referring to the end user when I said that. Maybe try something more CodeIgniter style: the controller method accepts a class that contains information about the page call, including the provided variables, and leave the controller to sort itself out.